# Can't easily iterate over shared array property of union type

Tags: typescript

I am building a nested folder UI that uses recursive data types

```js
interface TreeRoot { kind: "root", children: TreeBranch[]; }
interface TreeBranch { kind: "branch", children: TreeLeaf[]; }
interface TreeLeaf { kind: "leaf", children: undefined; }

type All = TreeRoot | TreeBranch | TreeLeaf;
```

Given the structures above, I would assume that this would be possible:

```js
/** Declare (but don't define) variable `example` for demonstrative purposes. */
declare const example: All;

(example.children || []).map(x => {
  console.dir(x);
});
```

The code above is not valid, however. It emits the following error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type
  ' (<U>(callbackfn: (value: TreeBranch, index: number, array: TreeBranch[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])
  | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: TreeLeaf, index: number, array: TreeLeaf[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])'
  has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)
```

`

Why is it that `none of those signatures are compatible with each other` and what can I do to allow for easier iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unions of function types are callable since [TypeScript 3.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types), but there are still [caveats](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#caveats): you can only call it of at most of the functions is overloaded or generic.  Since both `Array<TreeBranch>.map` and `Array<TreeLeaf>.map` are generic, you can't do it.  Luckily you can widen `A[] | B[]` to `(A | B)[]` before mapping, which is usually fine since the distinction between "an array that is either all `A`s or all `B`s" and "an array where each element is an `A` or a `B`" doesn't really matter when you call  `map()`:

So you want to use

```
((example.children || []) as (TreeBranch | TreeLeaf)[]).map(x => {
  console.dir(x);
});
```

or the slightly more type-safe

```
const children: Array<TreeBranch | TreeLeaf> = example.children || [];
children.map(x => console.dir(x));
```

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpQhASgex2ZAb2QGtQATALmQCIo8waAaZBAC2ABtyMRr1MAIShwQ7ANoBdANzIAvgChQkWIhQCIw0eyKkK1GgCMRYts1YduvfhggAZCHBhTZi5dHhI0th091kQKlpORxhzdi4eCD5kAFdAiBhQCHJXBQUwAE8ABxQAQU5OZABeb0xcfGQAHzLNEx0ajV8YaXTyCAROOAxWHBAAZwIIAA84AFtskOoCzlbkBQAKBZHxyYgAOgiraOqaqQBKZDh+5AWNLVNq2ub9g-WxuGyF4ZKAPiIFZF6BnBD18mAUGe+1achB6QQfUGFki1mQeSgIkyAB5zvU2FcmqF3qUVhM-lsoiBdsgXApCbx7o9nm9vv1fhsAUDhvtwUA)

This is covered in the question this duplicates.  Good luck!